# Potatoes were alive and sprouted on Mars: How were they preserved on the journey there?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, science, the-martian

Please note: The biology related aspects of this question are [posted here.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/could-potatoes-that-have-been-fridged-for-142-days-still-sprout-afterwards)

In "The Martian" (2015), the protagonist grows potatoes on Mars. We see him using seemingly fresh potatoes as his seeds.
[image]

[image]

The potatoes Mark used had been through a five-month journey through space without decomposing. Yet they still sprouted. In what way could they have been preserved to make both these things possible?

Comment: If I remember the book (which you should read if you're interested in this stuff) right, the potatoes are frozen. As to the rest, that may be better asked at the biology SE.

Comment: Why are you assuming the potatoes went through a 4 year journey?  They  were sent with the crew, so their transit time was only 5 or so months.

Comment: @Moo Oh, You're right. I just searched through the subtitles and found that they calculated that the rescue mission would take nine months of travel, not four years. The original journey date was probably set at a time when the distance between Earth and Mars was minimal.

Comment: @Fiksdal Cool! And guess I was wrong about them being frozen!

Comment: Biology SE link is broken...

Comment: @Necreaux http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/could-potatoes-that-have-been-fridged-for-142-days-still-sprout-afterwards

Comment: This is super normal, I grew up on a farm and we literally dump buckets of potatoes in the basement, eat some from the pile and plant the ones that are left the next year. Probably longer than 5 months later. Potatoes are dirt cheap because they are super easy to grow and store for long periods of time.

Comment: @Probst Hey, that's great. You could add that experience to the currently accepted answer.

Comment: @Probst Or you could answer here: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/could-potatoes-that-have-been-fridged-for-142-days-still-sprout-afterwards

Comment: OK I did both now

Comment: You must clean out your fridge way more often then I do...

Comment: Just an FYI; potatoes are incredibly hard to kill. They have to be cooked to actually prevent them from growing - as anyone who has found a long lost spud in the back of a cupboard covered in small roots will attest.

Comment: They were kept in a dark corner of Matt Damon's beer fridge.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I will begin this by stating that I am a PhD Student in potato post-harvest physiology and the sprouting of potatoes is an aspect that many people that work with this crop find very important.

It is certainly feasible that the potatoes, if refrigerated, would be able to sprout after several months. Some potatoes, including modern varieties, are able to sprout 2 years after their harvest if kept in a refrigerated environment. What is interesting about raw potatoes is that they are biologically alive and current preservation techniques aim to modify their urge to send sprouts to grow into a new plant. Other preservations techniques beyond refrigeration would include sprout inhibitors, chemicals that inhibit hormone mediated pathways that cause sprouting and package membrane technology. I imagine the packaging in this sci-fi movie is one that retards respiration and lengthens the life of the tubers.

However, the biggest issue with the plot resting on potato propagation is not the initial sprouting and growth. Rather, it is the rapid propagation of a second crop immediately after harvesting the first. Nearly every potato cultivar found in Europe and North America has a period of dormancy after harvest. This means that the tuber itself has hormonal controls that prevent any sprouting for a given period of time. While there are ways to overcome this, even with chemical sprout inducers, there is still a 1-2 month time period where the tubers from the previous crop will not sprout. Barring any chemicals to induce sprouting, it would take 3-4 months until the harvested tubers would sprout into a new crop.

[Wiltshire, J. J. J., and A. H. Cobb. "A review of the physiology of potato tuber dormancy." Annals of Applied Biology 129.3 (1996): 553-569](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1744-7348.1996.tb05776.x/abstract).

Comment: Definitely +1 for pointing out a plot hole by sciencing the hell out of it.

Comment: Excellent answer! You should be well equipped to answer here as well http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/45683/23347

Comment: Reminds me of NDG: https://i.imgur.com/bZ7IEFQ.webm

Comment: +1, You say "nearly every potato cultivar". Is it possible that he had one of the other cultivars, or that a new genetically engineered potato was brought with?

Comment: @DCShannon That would imply that they were *planning* on someone having to plant and cultivate these potatoes over a period of many months. That seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: Would some kind of rotation scheme have allowed the continual harvest? Nothing of the sort was depicted in the movie, of course, but he was an expert in relevant fields and may very well have been aware of the need to do so, if something like that could have worked.

Comment: @KRyan Not necessarily. I don't know anything about what cultivars don't require the delay. Maybe it would have made sense to bring one just by coincidence for other reasons.

Comment: TIL You can get a PhD in "Potato Post-Harvest Physiology", +1

Comment: Can you propagate potatoes by taking cuttings instead of sprouting from tubers? If so, perhaps he did that.

Comment: Might as well face it, you're addicted to spuds.

Comment: @WorseDoughnut Obligatory PhD reference: http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1056

Comment: *\*reads first line\** `I will begin this by stating that I am a PhD Student in potato post-harvest physiology` *\*checks out, didn't read the rest, +1 \**

Answer (score 56):

From the book:

> I am one lucky son of a bitch they aren’t freeze-dried or mulched. Why
>   did NASA send twelve whole potatoes, refrigerated but not frozen? And
>   why send them along with us as in-pressure cargo rather than in a
>   crate with the rest of the Hab supplies? Because Thanksgiving was
>   going to happen while we were doing surface operations, and NASA’s
>   shrinks thought it would be good for us to make a meal together.

It is a common practice for farmers to store loose potatoes in a cold room or basement during the winter and then plant them in the spring and that should closely match the condition of the refrigerated potatoes in the book.

Comment: This seems pretty realistic. Refrigerated potatoes, heck, even non-refrigerated potatoes can last eons, and still grow after said eons. Source: I've done this.

Comment: @GorchestopherH, Eons? Done this? *How old are you?*

Comment: When you think about it, potatoes are harvested in August/September, and planted in March, so thats a decent period of time when potatoes are stored...

Comment: @Separatrix Most people say "best thing since sliced bread" I say "best thing since dirt". Before dirt this place was the *worst*.

Comment: @GorchestopherH How long did you keep them? Didn't they decompose?

Comment: While the cold is important, as I understand it the truly vital consideration is moisture- moisture outright kills potatoes

Comment: Moisture can yeah, but it has to be pretty bad. You really don't need to do anything special to store piles of potatoes with say 5% or less spoilage. If the moisture levels are comfortable for people the potatoes will be fine.

Comment: It is interesting that in real life NASA heavily irradiates food before packaging, so in reality the potatoes would have been dead.  But then there wouldn't have been a story!

Comment: @GorchestopherH Read *The Way of Kings* by Brandon Sanderson sometime.  It's set in a world that's (mostly) without dirt, where people live on bare bedrock with plant and animal life adapted to such conditions...

Comment: Also, once having forgotten some potatoes in the far reaches of a cupboard: they will happily lay in a plastic-bag and sprout very slowly but happily for 6 months....